# Turn a .htc file's contents into 'regular' Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-components

I have a .htc file whose behaviour is attached to a div in my page (div#test). Within the file, there is a tag at the top, setting up the behaviour:

```
<PUBLIC:ATTACH EVENT="ondocumentready" FOR="element" ONEVENT="function1()" />
```

And throughout the file, there are calls to 'element', & this.element - which I presume are then referring to this div#test.

If I wanted to take the JS from this file, would it be possible to put into the main .html page? I've tried to make calls to the function on document load, but can't get my syntax correct.

I'm trying:

```
document.getElementById.('test').attachEvent(onlonad, function1());
```

Would appreciate any pointers, if I'm doing something basic wrong, or if anyone can tell me why doing it at all would be a bad idea! =)

Answer (score 0):

You have a dot in the wrong place, you're passing an undefined variable to the function and you're calling `function1()` instead of passing it:

```
document.getElementById.('test').attachEvent(onlonad,  function1());
//                     ^ this                ^   ^  ^ and these ^^
```

Correct syntax would be

```
document.getElementById('test').attachEvent("onload", function1);
```

Also note that only a few elements support the onload event - images, scripts and the body (which maps to window.onload).

If you want to make calls on document load, then it's awkward in IE because it doesn't support the document ready event that other browsers support.  There are ways around this, or you can use the window.onload event:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Code to execute when the window is loaded here 
}
```